# How can I show the number of different words from a text using bufferedreader and treeset?

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop, treeset

I tried something like this but I think that it will count the null lines as well.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
      String line;
    String[] words = new String[100];
    Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        words = line.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
            s.add(words[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s.size());
}
```

}

Comment: Well, `"".split("\\s+")` is `new String[] {""}`. You might need to handle that special case.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I handle that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
line = line.trim();
if(!line.isEmpty())
{
  words = line.split("\\s+");
  ...
}
```

This will take care of empty or "blank" lines (lines containing only spaces). It will also deal with non-empty lines that start with one or more spaces, since these can result in empty strings too.